# Explanation of Mapping structure in Veins

Tags: mapping, omnet++, veins, mixim

I try to understand and implement modifications to the Veins framework. Right now, I have some difficulties figuring out how the "Mapping" structure works. It is used to set the transmission power in "Mac1609_4.cc"

```
ConstMapping* txPowerMapping = createSingleFrequencyMapping(start, end, frequency, 5.0e6, power)
```

and to calculate received power, SNR and SINR in "Decider80211p.cc". Could you give some insight and some examples related to the structure manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping structure is from [MiXiM](http://mixim.sourceforge.net/), as Veins initially forked that project. MiXiM, however, is deprecated now and should not be used anymore [[2](https://github.com/omnetpp/mixim)]. Unfortunately, there is no real documentation available (anymore).

As replacement, there is either [INET](https://inet.omnetpp.org/), which also is supported by Veins, or, as it will be introduced in the next release, a much simpler representation of Signals, removing the Mapping structure [[4](https://github.com/sommer/veins/commit/4ea2e3dd6a055a83fb5f10f0e0ba441f2b68e49f)].

If you still need to understand the structure, you can have a look at [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1537713) where the authors explained the physical layer including the Mapping structure.